# Solution to operator equation, surjectivity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Suppose $T:V\to W$, where $V,W$ are banach spaces and $Tf = k$ (for instance $T$ might be an integral operator). They say that the equation has solution when $T$ is injective and so $T^{-1}$ exists. Why the surjectivity is neglected in the litterature? Is it related to the properties of infinite-dimensional spaces?

In the finite dimensional case of a function $f:R\to R$, the bijectivity is required for the existence of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Given an injective function $f : X \to Y$, there is a map $g : f(X) \to X$ such that $g\circ f = \operatorname{id}_X$ and $f\circ g = \operatorname{id}_{f(X)}$. The map $g$ is what is being referred to as $f^{-1}$. Note, this has nothing to do with Banach spaces, here $X$ and $Y$ can just be sets. Here $f(X)$ denotes the image of $f$. If you replace the codomain of $f$ by its image, then you get a genuine inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is injective, the solution may not exist for all $k\in W$. However, if the solution exists, it is unique. As a result, injectivity of $T$ assures the uniqueness (but not existence), whereas the surjectivity of $T$ assures the existence: for all $k\in W$ the solution $Tf = k$ exists (but may not be unique).

Comment: Ilya, spasibo for perfect answer.

Comment: @Bayes: pozhaluista